# HTML Parsing - Get Innermost HTML Tags

Tags: html, parsing

When I parse HTML I wish to obtain only the innermost tags for the entire document. My intention is to semantically parse data from the HTML doc.

So if I have some html like this

```
<html>
     <table>
           <tr><td>X</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Y</td></tr>
     </table>
</html>
```

I want `<td>X</td>` and `<td>Y</td>` alone. Is this possible using Beautiful Soup or lxml?

Answer (score 3):

In .NET I've used [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) library to do all html parsings easy. It loads DOM and you can select by nodes, in your case select nodes with no childs. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 2):

After you made sure your document is well-formed (by parsing it using lxml, for example), you could use XPath to query for all nodes that have no further child elements.

```
//*[count(*) = 0]
```

Comment: HTML not XHTML - so wont work because of <img> etc not being well formed.

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the few situations where you could actually use a Regular Expression to parse the HTML string.

```
\<(\w+)[^>]*>[^\<]*\</\1\s*>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use or DOM handling (i.e. in a browser) you can work with the *parentNode* attribute for all the tags and recursively count the total, and keep the largest one.

In javascript-pseudocode (tested on FireFox):

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var maxElementReference, maxParentNodeCount = 0;
var i;

for (i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {

    var count = recursiveCountParentNodeOn(allElements[i]);

    if (maxParentNodeCount < count) {
        maxElementReference = allElements[i];
        maxParentNodeCount = count;
    }
}
```